# Access combobox value

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a combobox, and a button, that makes runs a query with the values it gets from combobox, but it does not seem to get the right value.
[image]

I tried using

```
[Forms]![Kooli otsing]![Combobox]
```

or

```
[Forms]![Kooli otsing]![Combobox].[Text]
```

the query did not work, it seems like it does not get the value from combobox. because it worked with normal TextBox.

I ADDED EXPLAINING PICTURE!!!!!
[image]

ADDED PICTURE OF VBA EDITOR
[image]

ADDED PICTURE OF ERROR AND NO COMMENT AUTOCOMPLETE
[image]
[image]

Comment: How many columns are in your combo box?  Posting the rowsource for the combo box would help us debug.

Comment: @mwolfe02 183 columns in the combobox..rowsource? can you tell me what is that?

Comment: 183 must be the number of *rows* (I hope).  I'm curious about the number of *columns*.  The reason I ask is that a common practice with combo boxes is to have a hidden, bound column that is tied to the primary key (often an autonumber surrogate).  Unless you specify a column, referencing the textbox returns the bound (often hidden) column, not the data you see on the screen.  This is often confusing for new users.

Comment: @mwolfe02: oh...then i guess..only 1?

Comment: @mwolfe02: I added EXPLAINING PICTURE ON ORIGINAL POST

Comment: Try testing `[Forms]![Kooli otsing]![Combobox].Column(0)` and `[Forms]![Kooli otsing]![Combobox].Column(1)` and so forth. You can do this in the Immediate Window of the VBA editor while the form is open, and while it has a value selected in the combo box.

Comment: Also, what are the properties of the combo box? How many columns? What's the bound column? What's the rowsource/rowsource type? What are the column widths set to?

Comment: @David-W-Fenton : i didnt find the VBA editor thingy, but..combobox settings.. column count: 2, bound column : 1 , row source type : table/query  : SELECT [Haridusasutused].[ID], [Haridusasutused].[Nimetus] FROM Haridusasutused; list width : 2,54cm , width: 5,995cm, if you need more, i can give you

Comment: @Jaanus: `Ctl` + `G` will take you to the VBA editor Immediate Window.  It's an invaluable tool.

Comment: @mwolfe02 @David-W_fenton : i found the editor, though i dont really know how to handle it..its difficult..but i added the picture of it while its opened

Comment: Generally, with two columns in a combo box, you'll have two measurements in the width property, one for each column. If you leave one out, that column is sized to 1" (at least on US systems -- it might be a different unit with non-US regional settings). Nothing sticks out, here, but I must say your pictures are just not enlightening -- they aren't large enough to be clear, and they aren't providing the right information to answer the question. I still haven't a clue what your combobox is supposed to be doing or how it's doing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the latest comments you posted on your question, you want to use:

```
[Forms]![Kooli otsing]![Combo19].Column(1)
```

Here's why.  You said you have the following settings for your combobox:

- column count: 2
- bound column : 1
- row source type : table/query
- row source: `SELECT [Haridusasutused].[ID], [Haridusasutused].[Nimetus] FROM Haridusasutused;`

Column count of 2 is telling Access to use the first two columns from your rowsource (the only two columns in this case).  Bound column is telling access that the default value of the combobox should be the first column of the row source.  In this case, that would be `[Haridusasutused].[ID]`.  Often ID columns are autonumber fields.

The reason you were having problems is that `[Forms]![Kooli otsing]![Combo19]` was returning data from the ID column (most likely a number) not "Elva Gümnaasium".  By adding the `.Column(1)` you are telling Access to choose the data from the second column (`.Column` is a zero-based array) of the rowsource, ie, "Elva Gümnaasium".

**EDIT**: Alternatively, you can **change the bound column from 1 to 2** and leave the rest alone (ie, you won't need the `.Column(1)` part at all).

Comment: well i tried this, but the autocomplete doesn't even give me the Column(1) option..and when i write it manually. i get error : property not found...i also added pics to first post..check them :)

Comment: @Jaanus: Another option is simply to set the second column as the bound column (ie, change bound column from 1 to 2).  See my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

This works in my application:

```
[Forms]![Hour-registration]![mwkselect]

         ^form               ^combobox
```

Maybe try this to refresh:

```
Me.Requery
Me.Refresh
```

Comment: i have exactly same syntax as yours, but where do i put the ME.Refresh?

Comment: Properties of the combobox -> put some code behind the onchange event and copy the to lines ( requery / refresh )

Comment: now i have Private Sub Combo19_Change() ... Me.Refresh ... End Sub ... you mean like that? thats the whole sub. btw still does not work

Comment: I added EXPLAINING PICTURE ON ORIGINAL POST

Comment: Refreshing a form in one of the edit events of one of its controls is not a good idea, in my opinion, and probably not relevant to the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to step through debugger and search for the value through the watch window? For instance put a breakpoint into a button click event, then add [Forms] to the watch window and look into it.

Comment: i found the debugger..not really sure how to use it..umm..i put the breakpoint to Private Sub Search_Click() line..and then went to program..then i pressed the button and it just showed me the line..i think i used it wrong...ALSO..doesnt the debugger help me when i have error? because..i dont have an actual error, it doesnt just get the right value from the combobox.

Comment: I added EXPLAINING PICTURE ON ORIGINAL POST

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
[Forms]![Form1]![Combo1].[Text]
```