# Access shifts field values forward for no reason on an INSERT or APPEND query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2010

I am trying to build an Access database that allows my work site to catalog event type information.

When I have Access perform an Append or Update query, it shifts forward the combobox values that are put in the table, generally by 1. The table fields in question are linked to lookup tables, and Access does this no matter what the bound column is.

I've tried several things to remedy this, with no resolution:

1) I get the same results whether I link the lookup table or a null-sorting query for the event type.

2)  I tried 2 things in VBA to solve this, with the same result. First, I changed the VBA statement to directly reference the combobox for the value. Second, I'm aware that the combobox index starts at 0 instead of 1, so I tried shifting the number forward by 1 in VBA, which caused other problems.

3) I repaired the database.

4) I changed the Bound Column to 1 instead of 0 for the comboboxes

It looks like "[Access ComboBox save value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49787532/access-combobox-save-value)", "[Access combobox value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593372/access-combobox-value)" and "[Access 2007 Combobox displaying wrong results from table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38654190/access-2007-combobox-displaying-wrong-results-from-table)" are somewhat the same issue. Did I overlook something?

Here's the code for adding the information as a new entry:

```
Private Sub btn_AddOuting_Click()
   Dim strSQL As String
   Dim eventSlot As String, seasonStartSlot As String, seasonEndSlot As String, moneyReqSlot As String, prevSlot As String
   Dim eventDetails(5, 4) As Integer   '5 rows of event slots with 4 fields (event type, season start, season end, and money required)
   Dim slotNo As Integer, eventNo As Integer
   Dim boolAnyBlankReqFields As Boolean

   strSQL = ""

   For slotNo = 5 To 1 Step -1
      eventSlot = "cmb_Event" & slotNo
      seasonStartSlot = "cmb_StartOfSeason" & slotNo
      seasonEndSlot = "cmb_EndOfSeason" & slotNo
      moneyReqSlot = "cmb_MoneyRequired" & slotNo
      prevSlot = "cmb_Event" & (slotNo - 1)

      If eventSlot = "cmb_Event1" Then
         If (Forms("f_AddOuting").Controls(eventSlot) = 0 Or Forms("f_AddOuting").Controls(seasonStartSlot) = 0 Or _
             Forms("f_AddOuting").Controls(seasonEndSlot) = 0 Or Forms("f_AddOuting").Controls(moneyReqSlot) = 0) Then
            boolAnyBlankReqFields = True
            Me.lbl_Required.Visible = True
            If (Forms("f_AddOuting").Controls(eventSlot) = 0) Then
               Forms("f_AddOuting").Controls(eventSlot).BorderColor = RGB(255, 85, 85)
            End If
            If (Forms("f_AddOuting").Controls(seasonStartSlot) = 0) Then
               Forms("f_AddOuting").Controls(seasonStartSlot).BorderColor = RGB(255, 85, 85)
            End If
            If (Forms("f_AddOuting").Controls(seasonEndSlot) = 0) Then
               Forms("f_AddOuting").Controls(seasonEndSlot).BorderColor = RGB(255, 85, 85)
            End If
            If (Forms("f_AddOuting").Controls(moneyReqSlot) = 0) Then
               Forms("f_AddOuting").Controls(moneyReqSlot).BorderColor = RGB(255, 85, 85)
            End If
         Else
            eventDetails(1, 1) = Forms("f_AddOuting").Controls(eventSlot) + 1
            Forms("f_AddOuting").Controls(eventSlot).BorderColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            eventDetails(1, 2) = Forms("f_AddOuting").Controls(seasonStartSlot) + 1
            Forms("f_AddOuting").Controls(seasonStartSlot).BorderColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            eventDetails(1, 3) = Forms("f_AddOuting").Controls(seasonEndSlot) + 1
            Forms("f_AddOuting").Controls(seasonEndSlot).BorderColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            eventDetails(1, 4) = Forms("f_AddOuting").Controls(moneyReqSlot) + 1
            Forms("f_AddOuting").Controls(moneyReqSlot).BorderColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
         End If
      Else
         If (Forms("f_AddOuting").Controls(eventSlot).Enabled = False) Then
            eventDetails(slotNo, 1) = 1
            eventDetails(slotNo, 2) = 1
            eventDetails(slotNo, 3) = 1
            eventDetails(slotNo, 4) = 1
         Else
            eventDetails(slotNo, 1) = Forms("f_AddOuting").Controls(eventSlot)
            eventDetails(slotNo, 2) = Forms("f_AddOuting").Controls(seasonStartSlot)
            eventDetails(slotNo, 3) = Forms("f_AddOuting").Controls(seasonEndSlot)
            eventDetails(slotNo, 4) = Forms("f_AddOuting").Controls(moneyReqSlot)
         End If
      End If
   Next

   If boolAnyBlankReqFields = True Then
      MsgBox ("Fill in required information.")
   Else
      strSQL = "INSERT INTO t_OutingDetails (Event1, SeasonStart1, SeasonEnd1, MoneyRequired1, " _
            & "Event2, SeasonStart2, SeasonEnd2, MoneyRequired2, Event3, SeasonStart3, SeasonEnd3, MoneyRequired3, " _
            & "Event4, SeasonStart4, SeasonEnd4, MoneyRequired4, Event5, SeasonStart5, SeasonEnd5, MoneyRequired5) VALUES ('" _
            & eventDetails(1, 1) & ", " & eventDetails(1, 2) & ", " & eventDetails(1, 3) & ", " & eventDetails(1, 4) & ", " _
            & eventDetails(2, 1) & ", " & eventDetails(2, 2) & ", " & eventDetails(2, 3) & ", " & eventDetails(2, 4) & ", " _
            & eventDetails(3, 1) & ", " & eventDetails(3, 2) & ", " & eventDetails(3, 3) & ", " & eventDetails(3, 4) & ", " _
            & eventDetails(4, 1) & ", " & eventDetails(4, 2) & ", " & eventDetails(4, 3) & ", " & eventDetails(3, 4) & ", " _
            & eventDetails(5, 1) & ", " & eventDetails(5, 2) & ", " & eventDetails(5, 3) & ", " & eventDetails(5, 4) & ");"

      DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL

      MsgBox ("Entry submitted successfully.")

      boolAnyBlankReqFields = False

   End If

btn_AddOuting_Click_Exit:
   Exit Sub
btn_AddOuting_Click_Err:
   MsgBox Err & ": " & Err.Description
   Resume btn_AddOuting_Click_Exit
End Sub
```

Here's the code for updating the event type:

```
Private Sub btn_NewEvent1_Click()
   Dim strSQL As String

   If Me.cbo_NewEvent1 <> 0 Then
      strSQL = "UPDATE t_OutingDetails SET [t_OutingDetails].[Event1] = [Forms]![f_UpdateOutings]![cbo_NewEvent1] WHERE (((t_OutingDetails.ID)=[Forms]![f_UpdateOutings]![cbo_PlaceName]));"
      DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
      Me.txt_Event1.Requery
      Me.cbo_NewEvent1 = 0
   Else
      MsgBox ("No selection was made for the first event type.")
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Your post didn't get mach attention, right? Well I think you should consider narrowing it up to the exact problematic matter. The length deterrented me and I'm quit sure it deterrents others from 'diving in' so please try to be more specific, thank's

Comment: Actually, I appreciate your criticism; I was struggling to describe the problem. I may have managed to diagnose the problem by a different route. I set up a new, "test" database where I could focus on Access's behavior only involving comboboxes and lookup tables. This excludes queries for any kind of sorting, and uses an Access Wizard to build a button so I can't screw it up. I had the same problem in that case, suggesting that Access itself may somehow be broken.

Comment: Did you read thoroughly [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5621895/2398630)?
Did you implement your combos properties settings accordingally?

Comment: When I get home tonight I'll check those details closely to see if I've missed something. I know I checked some of them, and the consistency of this issue between the query builder and VBA, plus its appearance in a new, simplified database, made me believe the problem is in Access. (I will also say it's confusing knowing when to close and open tables, forms, and queries to make sure they're properly refreshed.)

Comment: It turns out the Bound Column property was the issue. I got that "glitch" when it wasn't set to the column that had the string values. Consider me schooled. 